# Create more than one rpm with nebula.ospackage plugin

Tags: gradle

I am using the bebula.ospackage plugin with gradle to create a specific rpm.
So the following is added

```
ospackage {

    packageName = "rpmA"
    packageGroup ="..."
    ...
}
```

In this way i will have an rpm creation named rpmA.

What i need is to create more than one rpm packages for other issues.
rpmA, rpmB, etc
I cannot just simply put the above block with different parameters since the last one will overwrite all and i will still get one rpm.

Any idea. How to create multiple rpms?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Gradle assumes that a project can have multiple artifacts, but the nebula.ospackage plugin only handles one RPM per (sub-)project.

You can still do this by creating a multi-project build. There is an excellent guide at [gradle guides](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/), or alternatively the reference manual is [also at gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Set up one subproject per RPM:

```
rootproject/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  subproject1/
  subproject2/
```

Tell the root project to include the subprojects using the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include 'subproject1', 'subproject2'
```

This setup allows you to configure most of the subprojects' RPM settings in the `build.gradle` of `rootproject`, using for example the `subprojects {` construct.

(I think limiting each project to one RPM is a reasonable limitation, since it makes the DSL much simpler. Normally the desirable practice is to deliver a software project in as few RPM packages as possible. When you need several RPMs, you probably want to build the source code in separate projects, and keep the source project separately versioned, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to create multiple rpm of your choice:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "3.2.0"
}


task one(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'one-pack'
    version = '1.0.0'
    release = '1'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX

    from('./src/main/resources') {
        into 'apps/lib/'
    }
}

task two(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'two-pack'
    version = '2.2.0'
    release = '2'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.ospackage'

group 'com.avishek'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Once you have this gradle file, please build them as follows:

```
 ./gradlew clean two one
```

You will have two different rpm files created as follows:

```
./build/distributions/one-pack-1.0.0-1.i386.rpm
./build/distributions/two-pack-2.2.0-2.i386.rpm
```